# P4python needs to check what files are changed in a specific changelist

Tags: python-3.x, p4python

Using python and  p4python I'm trying to shows the files that are changed in a changelist. I

```
result = p4.run_describe("2631893", tagged = 0)
```

This shows the files in a change list and not what is

```
result = p4.run_diff("-sa")
```

shows all the changed files in the client. What I am looking for is a run_diff similar functions that gives the name of changed files in a specific changelist. Is it possible?

UPDATE:
After thinking twice, I came to the fact that I shiuld probably write what I am trying to do
The idea is this that I check out some simulink models , run code generation for all models. There are already some generated code in the depot that belongs to each Simulink model. I need to check if the models generate the same code that is already in depo. If they are not the same then the name of those files should be printed. So my strategy is this
1) Make a changelist. DONE
2) check iut the models in that changelist DONE
3) check out all the already gererated files in a different change list (lets call it CL 2) DONE
4) generate code DONE
5) Revert unchanged files from that changelist (dont know how to do. It should only revert unchanged files from THAT Changelist e g. CL2) 
6) if CL2 is empty then fine. Otherwise print the file name.

```
P4.revert('-a' , CL2)
```

Does not work. And i dont inow how to get the number of file in a CL from python.